# Please help to identify SOT23-5 packaged "T1-R17"

Tags: components, identification

Picture of good component: [image]

Picture of bad component: [image]

These are photos of identical twins. The first is in perfect health, the other burned up and rendered the Sony VAIO PCG-8111L laptop in came from, useless. I would love to ID this 5-pin package, (T1-R17), and replace it. I have searched until I am blue in the face, but not sure if I was searching correctly.

Comment: It's possible that there is more writing on the underside of the IC.

Comment: I'd be careful with your assumption that the failed part is the cause rather than just a symptom. That's a common mistake made by undergraduates. Most likely if you replace it and return the board to service (ceteris paribus) it will simply explode again. However, you will need to replace the part eventually, of course, so it's still a valid question.

Comment: Listen to him, he is the doctor of fried parts.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's a Low Dropout Regulator of some sort (probably 3.3V). The code will not the actual part number, rather a specific package code (which makes it very hard to find unless you at least know the manufacturer)
Have you measured the voltages on the pins of the working part?

Comment: Alternatively, check pins for conductivity with identifiable signals (0v is easy!) but other supplies can be identified from datasheets of other parts. When you have identified a few pins, compare with datasheets of common LDO regulators. When you find a match, its app circuits will give you clues about the remaining pins.